# What is the engine shell temperature?

Tags: aircraft-design, jet-engine, aircraft-performance, engine-design

What are the highest temperature locations in the outer shell on an aircraft engine? Particularly, modern turbofans like the Trent 900 for example. I'm interested in the temperature constraints of pylons that's why.

Comment: By "engine shell" do you mean the [nacelle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nacelle)?

Comment: No, the shell of the bare engine. The part where the engine mounts are installed (Inside the nacelle).

Comment: Not the combustion cans ?